# Android : Google Hangouts type layout

Tags: android

I was sort of wondering how could the google hangouts type layout be achieved? I do notice that they are fragments, but how are they swipable?

Does anyone have an idea? A good blog on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses SlidingPanelLayout. See this for detailed information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html